# KendoUI cascading drop-downs does not update after binding once

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am using KendoUI cascading Drop-downs and it seems to be working fine for most part but it seems to have a little problem. However, I think it is a problem with my implementation NOT with the tool because on their Demo  page [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist) it seems to work fine. Also, I tried to follow the code exactly as it as to make sure that I do get the same behavior. Now, I am seeing following behavior:

- I select an option in parent drop down and then click on the child drop down then it calls the conroller action correctly
- It continues to do that **as far as** results for child dropdown are empty
- **Once** it gets some value to bind child drop-down with, it stops making any call to the controller despite of what I choose in parent drop-down or child-dropdown.

I am not sure why it happens. Following is my code snippet:

**Controller code**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FindAlignmentsByTeamId(int teamId)
{
    var teams = Client.GetAlignmentsByTeamId(teamId);
    return Json(teams, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**.cshtml code**

```
@* Perent Dropbox *@

<tr>
    <td>EmployeeID</td>
    <td><b>@Model.EmployeeId</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Team</td>
    <td>
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
              .Name("Team")
              .DataTextField("TeamName")
              .DataValueField("TeamId")
              .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetAllTeams", "Employee")))
        )
    </td>
</tr>

@* Child DropBox *@


@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("Alignment")
    .DataTextField("AlignmentName")
    .DataValueField("AlignmentId")
    .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("FindAlignmentsByTeamId", "Employee").Data("FilterAlignment"))
           .ServerFiltering(true)
    )
    .CascadeFrom("teamId")
    .AutoBind(false)
)

<script type="text/javascript">
    function FilterAlignment() {
        return {
            teamId: $("#Team").val()
        }
    };
</script>
```

I am not sure what happens after it is bound successfully with a value for the first time so that it has a reason to believe that now it does not have to be checking on any OnChange() events anymore? Any ideas?

Comment: Where's your parent drop-down? You need to post that too.

Comment: However, looking at the code, even without the parent drop-down, I can see what the problem is. The id you're using in the javascript code is different from the one in `.CascadeFrom()` (one is `Team`, the other one is `teamId`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` of your parent `DropDownList` is "Team", not "teamId". You need to update your child `DropDownList` to cascade from the correct `id`:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("Alignment")
      .DataTextField("AlignmentName")
      .DataValueField("AlignmentId"            
      .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("FindAlignmentsByTeamId", "Employee").Data("FilterAlignment"))
                .ServerFiltering(true)
      )
      .CascadeFrom("Team")
      .AutoBind(false)
)
```